# If $a = b - c$, $b = c - d$ and $c = d - a$, then $\frac ab + \frac bc + \frac cd + \frac da$ is equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a = b - c$,  $b = c - d$ and $c = d - a$, then $\frac ab +  \frac bc + \frac cd + \frac da$ is equal to?

Sorry, a bit more context to this question. This comes from the UKMT Intermediate Maths Challenge paper in 1997. I was helping my son solve this and could not solve this. I finally found that $a = -b$ and $a = -d$ and hence $b=d$. Bit stuck thereafter! Anyone can offer a nudge along, please?

Comment: **Missing context or other details:** Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Hint: you have three relations, use them to express $b,c,d$ in terms of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to answer this. The trick is to express everything in terms of $d$.

It follows from the relations given that,  $a = -d, b = d, c = 2d$, substituting these, we find that $\frac ab +  \frac bc + \frac cd + \frac da = \frac 12$.

Many thanks to @dxiv for the helpful suggestions!!